# Charting library for Flex

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I'm starting to develop a website with flex. I need a charting library. It's very important to have good looking and interactive charts. I have been testing charts included in flex builder and fusion charts for flex.
Does any body know any other charting library for flex? I don't mind the cost of the library. I prefer to pay and have a great chart.
Greetings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ILOG Elixir:  http://ilog.com/products/ilogelixir

and

Degrafa:  http://www.degrafa.org/samples/

or

Axiis:  http://www.axiis.org/

Comment: I think your first link is meant to be http://www.ilog.com/products/ilogelixir/

Comment: haha.... yea I did.  I sent that to a buddy that told me he heard the internet was running out of bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check [Flexmonster](http://www.flexmonster.com) pivot table and chart component.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.anychart.com/home/ is a good one.

But it also depends on what you need to chart. Why aren't the Flex ones good enough for you? What do you need? How do you want to interact with it?

Comment: For example. Pie chart in fusion charts looks better than pie chart in flex.
To interact I want the user to click in one serie of the chart and show new data. That's very simple and most of libraries do that.
Principally I want a good looking presentation. As better as possible and I don't mind to pay for that. And fusionCharts looks better than flex chart.
Any other suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: anychart will do that for you if you want. More of a component than a library, but it still gives you lots of control.