# Free Flex Chart library

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I am looking for a) the easiest to use free chart library and b) a chart library with a lot of features for Flex. I am looking for basic line and bar graphs. What are the options available?

PS: Library size may be an issue for the application I am trying to write.

Comment: Why not to choose standard Flex data visualization?

Comment: These components are free since Flex 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try out [FusionCharts for Flex](http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/). They have a completely free license available, which is the same as their paid license, except that there would a small label saying "By FusionCharts".

They come from the reputed [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/) family

You should really check out their exhaustive [chart gallery](http://www.fusioncharts.com/flex/gallery/charts/) for Flex

Answer (score 1):

[Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) is an open source AS3 data visualization library.  There are a couple of chart available as well as a whole swag of other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362021/charting-library-for-flex) post, 
[BirdEye](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/) is another good one I've used in production, check out their examples on the wiki page.

Answer (score 1):

[Axiis](http://www.axiis.org/), [Open Flash Chart](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/) both provided good inspiration for me when I eventually rolled out my own charting engine (private).

No charting engine met my needs, but if you just want basic bars/lines, these should be good.